# Summarize the occurrences of records in sql

Tags: sql

So I have this data:

```
ProdNum   WhseNum
1000-111   1
1000-111   2 
1005-555   1 
1002-456   2
```

as i have over 1,048,576 records in sql, i can't paste complete in excel to do pivot. I can't figure out a way to do this in sql. How do I return a set of records which state?

```
ProdNum   Occurrences 
1000-111  2
1005-555  1
1002-456  1
```

Comment: This is called an aggregation query.  It uses `group by`, a fundamental part of the SQL language.  You should learn a bit about the language if you want to use it effectively.

Comment: Use `Group By` + `Count(*)`.

Answer (score 0):

As was stated in the comments, you need to use a group by clause and a count.  Something like the following should do it:

```
select ProdNum, COUNT(*) as Occurrences
from table
group by ProdNum
```